# Sea is higher than land when importing large real world terrain

Tags: unity, terrain, heightmap

[image: Sample image]

I am trying to import some real world terrain into Unity with the help of Global Mapper. The data I am using is download from CGIAR SRTM(http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/,http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/srtmdata/). The land part works well but I am having trouble with the sea part.

[image: Weird thing]

This is a larger view of that weird thing in the first image. This strange is actually the sea. This is happening because I am using the gradient shader. Lokks like:

[image: nothing]

The sea is represented with white, but when Unity reading the .raw file, the white means the highest part. Does anyone know how to deal with problems like this? Thanks very march.

Comment: Have you considered processing your input file so that the ocean is the darkest colour instead of the brightest?

Comment: Just go in with a fill tool and change the pure white bits to pure black probably.

Comment: It surely would work, but the plain are so close to the lowest black color. This might make there no different between plain and sea alone the coastline.